# False religion in kali yuga? Are we following false people in kali yuga?

Tags: shiva-purana, kali-yuga

In Shiva purana, lord vishnu creates a jinx with bald head with cloth to his face and a book in his hands. He asks jinx to propagate false religion to asuras saying it is the actual vedic dharma. He gave a boon to that jinx that in kali yuga his religion (false one)would be followed as and becomes popular. I got a strange idea that what if great saints like buddha, adi shankaracharya who debated against vedic principles are actually that very jinx? I am sorry for asking like this but please advise.

Comment: Bald head does not help identifying who it will be because it is not only Adi Shankara or Buddha who had bald heads. Vaishnava acharyas like Madhava etc also had shaven heads. It is just a sign that they had taken Sannyasa.

Comment: Different sects have different views on bald head avatar. Adi Shankara didn't definitely argue against Vedic principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is

> I got a strange idea that what if great saints like buddha, adi shankaracharya who debated against vedic principles are actually that very jinx?

No comments on Buddha here, since Buddhism is not an Astika doctrine.

Adi Shankara, whether one agrees with him or disagrees with him, was a staunch follower of vedas. He was the foremost proponent of advaita-vedAnta school, which he derived from upanishads, bhagavad gIta and brahmasUtras.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shankara

> Shankara is most known for his systematic reviews and commentaries (Bhasyas) on ancient Indian texts. Shankara's masterpiece of commentary is the Brahmasutrabhasya (literally, commentary on Brahma Sutra), a fundamental text of the Vedanta school of Hinduism.[44]
>
> His commentaries on ten Mukhya (principal) Upanishads are also considered authentic by scholars,[44][46] and these are: Bhasya on the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad, the Chandogya Upanishad, the Aitareya Upanishad, the Taittiriya Upanishad, the Kena Upanishad,[49] the Isha Upanishad, the Katha Upanishad, the Mundaka Upanishad, the Prashna Upanishad, and the Mandukya Upanishad.[50][51] Of these, the commentary on Mandukya, is actually a commentary on Madukya-Karikas by Gaudapada.[51]
>
> Other authentic works of Shankara include commentaries on the Bhagavad Gita (part of his Prasthana Trayi Bhasya).

To say the Adi Shankara argued against vedic principles, is therefore incorrect.